# Javascript: filling undefind properties in object from a default object

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to fill in undefined properties into an object using values from a default object.

I am basically looking to do something like underscores's "_.default" function.

Here is what I have:

```
     defaults: function(anyObject){

      var argArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1);

       for(var key in argArray){
        if(anyObject[key] == null){
            anyObject[key] = argArray[key];
          } 
        } return anyObject; 
       }
```

I call the function with the following passed:

```
defaults({extension : ".jpeg"}, {extension : ".gif", quality : "high"});
```

and I want it to return the following:

```
=> {extension : ".jpeg", quality : "high"}
```

any suggestions?

Comment: What does your current code do?

Comment: it returns me something like: {extension : ".jpeg"} {extension : ".gif", quality : "high"} extension = .jpeg

Comment: I know I am having a problem with the argArray

Comment: http://underscorejs.org/#defaults do what you want exactly.

Comment: {extension : ".jpeg", quality : "high"}

Answer (score 1):

I'd try something like this:

```
defaults: function(defaults) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);

    for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        var arg = args[i];

        for (var key in arg) {
            if (!(key in defaults)) {
                defaults[key] = arg[key];
            }
        }
    }

    return defaults;
}
```

This will only add new keys to `defaults`.

Comment: The only problem here is that we are using another loop. what if we had hundreds of other arguments.

Comment: @ShafiRazzack: This is pretty much how underscore does it: http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
defaults: function(obj, def) {
  Object.keys(def).forEach(function(key) {
    obj[key] = obj[key] || def[key]; 
  });
  return obj;
}
```