# Intersecting objects with a default object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I have an object with objects, which are basically settings per guild. In these objects are various configuration options that the admin of their guild can change.

```
{
  "1": {
    "foo": "Hello World",
    "bar": "Ello World",
    "roo": {
      "doo": "oof"
    }
  },
  "2": {
    "foo": "foo bar foo bar",
    "bar": "World! Hi!",
    "roo": {
      "doo": "boo!"
    }
  }
}
```

And I have a default object for those settings.

```js
const Default = {
  foo: "Hello, World!",
  bar: "Foo example",
  roo: {
    doo: "boo"
  }
};
```

When I add a new key to the default object, I'd like all the objects in the settings to adapt to these new changes and add only the new key with the default value. Although, I don't know which key is new, because only at startup I want the script to check for new values and add those to the existing settings.

Also, settings can have nested objects but no arrays - arrays are only used as value. I've looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400595/javascript-filling-undefind-properties-in-object-from-a-default-object) but I cannot seem to figure out how to add nested object support

For instance, I could add a `"foobarexample"` key to the default object, and as default value `"ello"` and it would add that to all the settings. I should also be able to add this to the 'roo' object and it would still update, even though 'roo' isn't new

If you have any suggestions, they're much appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfect use case for JavaScript's prototypal inheritance:

```js
const defaultObj = {
  foo: "Hello, World!",
  bar: "Foo example",
  roo: {
    doo: "boo"
  }
};

const obj = Object.assign(Object.create(defaultObj), { foo: "New foo" });
const anotherObj = Object.create(defaultObj);

console.log('obj.foo', obj.foo);
console.log('anotherObj.foo', anotherObj.foo);
console.log('obj.bar', obj.bar);

defaultObj.bar = "New bar";

console.log('obj.bar', obj.bar);
console.log('anotherObj.bar', anotherObj.bar);

defaultObj.foobarexample = "ello";

console.log('obj.foobarexample ', obj.foobarexample );
console.log('anotherObj.foobarexample ', anotherObj.foobarexample );
```

In this code, all of the objects created from `defaultObj` with `Object.create` have a reference on `defaultObj`. When trying to access a property of the resulting objects, the property will be looked up in the object itself, and then in `defaultObj` if not found. `defaultObj` can safely be mutated after the objects have been created (it cannot be reassigned though, because the objects created would keep a reference on the previous one).

Comment: "*This is a perfect use case for prototypal inheritance*" - yes it is. But why use a `new Default()` constructor function? Just go for `Object.create`.

Comment: Thank you for your solution! I understand how you did it, it worked perfectly like it should :]

Answer (score 0):

https://repl.it/@HenriDe/httpsreplitHenriDeIntersectinobjectswithdefault

this one should work for what you are looking for.

```
const defaultValues = {
  "1" : {
    foo: 'Hello, World!',
    bar: 'Foo example',
    roo: {
      doo: 'boo',
      newest: {
        goal: "dodo"
      }
    },
    hello: "world"
  }
};


function eachRecursive(obj, defaultValues, level = 0){
    // check each key amongst the defaults
    for (var k in defaultValues){ 
      // if our original object does not have key attach it + default values associated 
      if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        obj[k] = checkWith[k]
      }
      // keep calling as long as value is object 
      if (typeof obj[k] == "object" && obj[k] !== null)
          eachRecursive(obj[k], checkWith[k], level + 1);
      }
    }
}

// for each of the specific entries check
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
  eachRecursive(data[key], defaultValues["1"])
}

console.log(data["1"])
```

Comment: Links in answers are encouraged for background and clarification, but the answer should answer the question even if the link stops working.

Comment: There were some syntax errors and `checkWith` was undefined, but I got it to work, but the contents of `roo` didn't get updated and `hello` is undefined, but that might be because I just initialised `let checkWith = {};` in the function head. Can you maybe update your answer?

Comment: Based on the domain/URL of your link(s) being the same as, or containing, your user name, you appear to have linked to your own site/a site you're affiliated with. If you do, you *must disclose that it's your site in your post*. If you don't disclose affiliation, it's considered spam. Please see: [What signifies "Good" self promotion?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212) and [the help center on self-promotion](/help/promotion). Disclosure must be explicit, but doesn't need to be formal. When it's your own *personal* content, it can just be something like "on my site…", "on my blog…", etc.

Comment: Either the answer was incomplete, because there were missing variables, or you didn't test it at all/forgot to include something, @Henri De Bel.