# Not able to update a class property in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, prototype

How does this translate to ES6?

```js
function Mock() { };
Mock.prototype.foo = 'bar';
var obj = new Mock();
console.log(obj.foo);
Mock.prototype.foo = 'Something else';
console.log(obj.foo);
```

I've tried this:

```js
class Mock {
  foo = 'bar';
}
const obj = new Mock();
console.log(obj.foo);
Mock.prototype.foo = 'Something else';
console.log(obj.foo);
```

But it doesn't work because the class properties are actually attached directly to the instanciated object instead of being attached to `Mock.prototype`.

Comment: You can access to parent foo from __proto__ `console.log(obj.__proto__.foo); //'Something else'`

Comment: @DenisStukalov what if I only have a reference on `Mock`?

Comment: @DenisStukalov, better not suggest the use of a deprecated property

Comment: @ChristopherRonning how would it help? I want to update the `prototype` so that it also updates all of the object instances

Comment: Heh sorry, deleted my comment because I couldn't format the code. I guess I misunderstood what you wanted though. What exactly do you want? Do you want to change a property of all objects of type `Mock` AFTER you've instantiated them? If so, can I ask why? Or do you just want to set a default property value?

Comment: I was just curious, I just answered this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62178687/intersecting-objects-with-a-default-object-in-javascript/62179205 and I realized I was unable to translate it to ES6

Comment: If you're using class fields, that's not an ES6 class.

Comment: @Bergi really? What is it then?

Comment: @GuerricP Class fields are experimental syntax from a [stage-3 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields). They might become part of ES2021 or later, if at all. In ES6, you should just write a `constructor()` to create the property, which also makes it clear that they're created on instances.

Comment: Ok @Bergi thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems an antipattern to me to change the prototype. But if you really want this, you should just continue to use the same syntax as before for defining the property:

```js
class Mock { }
Mock.prototype.foo = "bar";

const obj = new Mock();
console.log(obj.foo);
Mock.prototype.foo = "Something else";
console.log(obj.foo);
```

Comment: If it's an antipattern why is it allowed? For backwards compatibility with the legacy web?

Comment: That is an interesting question, but that would be for the tc39 group to answer. Anyway a language specification can never hope to eliminate all antipatterns.

Comment: OK, I thought it was a good way to solve this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62178687/intersecting-objects-with-a-default-object-in-javascript/62179205. This may be out of the scope of the question, but how would you solve it? With `Proxy`? Something else?

Comment: @GuerricP It's allowed because it would be hard to prevent it. Also it's quite useful to overwrite methods, should you ever need to. It's still a bad idea to treat a prototype object as a mutable storage.

Answer (score 0):

- Because in ES6, the .prototype property of classes is not writable
  and not configurable
- If you wanna change then use **Object.defineProperty**

```js
    class Mock {
      foo = 'bar'
    }
    const obj = new Mock()
    console.log(obj.foo)
    
    Object.defineProperty(obj, 'foo', {
      value: 'Something else',
      writable: true,
      enumerable: false,
      configurable: false
    })
    
    console.log(obj.foo)
```