# Is there a Class equivalent to prototype attributes?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class, prototypal-inheritance

If I have the following code:

```js
function Thing() {}
Thing.prototype.cache = {};

var a = new Thing();
var b = new Thing();

a.cache === b.cache // true
```

How might I re-write this using [proper Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)?

I know about [public class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields), but those are defined on the *instance* rather than on the class prototype.

```js
// For Example:
class Thing {
  cache = {}
}

var a = new Thing();
var b = new Thing();

a.cache === b.cache // false
```

Comment: It seems like it would be easier to move the cache to be declared as a variable above the class. It doesn't feel like the type of thing that belongs on the prototype to begin with.

Comment: It's recommended not to put mutable objects on the prototype where they are shared. Use a `static` class field instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no class syntax to put non-methods on the prototype, you'll have to slap them on afterwards, like this:

```js
class Thing {}
Thing.prototype.cache = {}

// Example usage //

const thing1 = new Thing()
const thing2 = new Thing()
thing1.cache.x = 2
console.log(thing2.cache.x)
```

However, putting mutable data on the prototype is seen by many as magical and difficult to follow. Here's another way to achieve a very similar effect.

```js
// This can alternativly be a static, private variable on the class.
const thingCache = {}

class Thing {
  cache = thingCache
}

// Example usage //

const thing1 = new Thing()
const thing2 = new Thing()

thing1.cache.x = 2
console.log(thing2.cache.x)
```

But, what I would really recommend is to just make this property a static property on the class - that's what static properties are for, sharing a single piece of data between many instances.

```js
class Thing {
  static cache = {}
}

// Example usage //

Thing.cache.x = 2
console.log(Thing.cache.x)

// In some rare scenarios where you only have the instance,
// and not the original class, you can still retrieve the original class

const thing1 = new Thing()
const thing2 = new Thing()

thing1.constructor.cache.x = 2
console.log(thing2.constructor.cache.x)
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. Yeah, the context for this is refactoring some old code, so if there is an opportunity to remove some anti-patterns, the new code doesn't have to be exactly 1-to-1, just that 1-to-1 is a "safer" conversion.

Answer (score 1):

What you have implemented is called [class field](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields), as you noticed in your case it's an equivalent of:

```
class Thing {
  constructor() {
    this.cache = {};
  }
}
```

You have no other choice than attaching it to the prototype just like you'd do in ES5, because everything you declare inside a class is either:

- A class field (attached to the instance)
- A method (attached to the prototype)
- A static field (attached to the class)

```js
class Thing {
}

Thing.prototype.cache = {};

const obj1 = new Thing;
const obj2 = new Thing;

console.log(obj1.cache === obj2.cache);
```

I have posted a similar question here: [Not able to update a class property in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62179617/not-able-to-update-a-class-property-in-es6)

As a side note, as you're not using a `constructor`, the `class` is needless so you could write this:

```js
const proto = { cache: {} };

const obj1 = Object.create(proto);
const obj2 = Object.create(proto);

console.log(obj1.cache === obj2.cache);
```

Comment: Class fields has left the proposal stage actually. They are part of this year's release: https://github.com/tc39/proposals/blob/master/finished-proposals.md

Comment: The class field _isn't_ shared though, which is what I'm looking to maintain. `class T{ constructor(){ this.cache = [] } }; var a = new T; var b = new T; a.cache === b.cache // false`.

Comment: What doesn't suit you in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You want to create a [static class field](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields#public_static_fields)

Then define getters and setters based off the class name.

> Public static fields are useful when you want a field to exist only once per class, not on every class instance you create. This is useful for caches, fixed-configuration, or any other data you don't need to be replicated across instances.
>
> Public static fields are declared using the static keyword. They are added to the class constructor at the time of class evaluation using [Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty). They are accessed again from the class constructor.

> - Fields without initializers are initialized to undefined.
> - Public static fields are not reinitialized on subclasses, but can be accessed via the prototype chain.
> - When initializing fields, `this` refers to the class constructor. You can also reference it by name, and use `super` to get the superclass constructor (if one exists).

```js
class Thing {
  static _cache = {};
  
  get cache() { return Thing._cache; }
  set cache(newValue) { Thing._cache = newValue; }
}

var a = new Thing();
var b = new Thing();

b.cache.key = "value";

console.log(a.cache === b.cache);
console.log(a.cache)
```

Comment: You don't even need to use getters and setters. You could just do `class Thing { static _cache = {}; cache = Thing._cache }`

Comment: @ScottyJamison You do though, since saying `a = { "key2": "value2" }` won't assign that same object to `Thing._cache`, it'll just change where the reference is pointing for instance `a`

Comment: That's no different from the O.P.'s original solution of storing this cache object on the prototype. Someone assigning to someInstance.cache would just shadow the prototype value, and no other instance would see the update. But, that's still a good point.

Comment: @ScottyJamison OP was wanting to do the `*.prototype.cache = {}` thing inside the class itself and not saying `*.prototype.cache = {}` outside of the class definition. This is exactly what OP wants

Comment: Yes, I'm not saying your answer is wrong at all. You're giving the O.P. exactly what they wanted. I was simply mentioning that the getter/setter in your solution was not necessary because you're not doing anything with the getter/setter except mimicking property access, so might as well just do property access directly - unless you find getter/setter more readable, or you want to be able to assign to the value (not a necessary feature since the O.P.'s original version didn't have that feature either)

Answer (score 0):

As Scotty Jamison said, the class syntax still does not provide a way to create fields on the prototype itself, so you'll have to do it with `[class].prototype.field`. However, if you wish to do so within the class declaration itself, you can use static blocks:

```
class Thing {
    static {
        this.prototype.boofar = {};
    }
}
```

Code inside a static block will run when the class is initialized, with `this` bound to the class itself. This is arguably more confusing than just assigning the value after the class declaration, as using `static` might suggest a static property, not an inherited one. Still, it's nice for the class to not depend on external code.